# Generating RSA public key on linux, converting to base64, and importing into VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, rsa

I would like to hardcode a string into a VB.NET program containing the base64 String representation of an RSA public key I generate on a linux computer.

On the linux box:

- I use ssh-keygen to generate the keypair
- I use PHP to convert .ssh/id_rsa.pub to base64 using base64_encode()

In the VB Code, I hardcode the output I generated above into a string variable:

```
Dim publicKey As String = "QUFBQUIzTnphQzF5YzJFQUFBQUJJd0FBQVFFQTRrNHNPOFhyajhJUkM4WGhEMVJQYlhJbUROTnVwdEpvUEtYNzNhcHc1M0NFUGE3VVNRY0U2SXhyNENWM2FhVXBtR1Fsb1I4akNLVkNoUnhzOUVnT3JQcVNGMTFjL3ZPNzluMXdkU1VWZjhreC9uY1NiV25UUXBtb1paNlN5ZUM3ekhMbWh1Z0o5OWdsVjB3bXBhTXpPeitHa0JBeFBPYlV0MzFYalMxMlBzM0ZUZFBla2s5T0ptMFJxc1plM3krbHU2UURZbDEyejJyTU9lbFhJS2IxSUZ1SnF6SThqL2Y4Q3V2dGxCSmxhelRBWlkyekF1WTZWMXU4c2JnUmE2MTBxMzM3dUdMODErbytCUkRzS0dwN0xBRmRwM1R2ekE3MDZPeFVSSEF0YmRZOVkzaXFISFFzQ3ZQWXBqcVQ0MHVlZ1RHY05jd2JCdjZxa2xlckk2K25Ndz09"

Dim myRsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
myRsa.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey))
```

I get a runtime exception about "bad version of provider"

Comment: Why would you expect OpenSSH's proprietary RSA key format to be identical to Microsoft's proprietary key format? Also, the RSA key in id_rsa.pub is already base64 encoded, why do it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd convert it (using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->loadKey(base64_decode('QUFBQUIzTnphQzF5YzJFQUFBQUJJd0FBQVFFQTRrNHNPOFhyajhJUkM4WGhEMVJQYlhJbUROTnVwdEpvUEtYNzNhcHc1M0NFUGE3VVNRY0U2SXhyNENWM2FhVXBtR1Fsb1I4akNLVkNoUnhzOUVnT3JQcVNGMTFjL3ZPNzluMXdkU1VWZjhreC9uY1NiV25UUXBtb1paNlN5ZUM3ekhMbWh1Z0o5OWdsVjB3bXBhTXpPeitHa0JBeFBPYlV0MzFYalMxMlBzM0ZUZFBla2s5T0ptMFJxc1plM3krbHU2UURZbDEyejJyTU9lbFhJS2IxSUZ1SnF6SThqL2Y4Q3V2dGxCSmxhelRBWlkyekF1WTZWMXU4c2JnUmE2MTBxMzM3dUdMODErbytCUkRzS0dwN0xBRmRwM1R2ekE3MDZPeFVSSEF0YmRZOVkzaXFISFFzQ3ZQWXBqcVQ0MHVlZ1RHY05jd2JCdjZxa2xlckk2K25Ndz09'));
$rsa->setPublicKey();

$publickey = $rsa->getPublicKey(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_XML);

echo $publickey;
```